# Number pattern using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am having a bit of trouble with recursion, my first input will be the starting number and it will keep being subtracted by the second input. Ex) 12 and 3 as inputs and the output is 12 9 6 3 0 3 6 9 12. The printNumPattern method is the recursion method.

```
private static void printNumPattern(int num1, int num2) {
        int temp = num1;

        System.out.println(num1);

        if(num1 <= 0) {
            
            if(num1 == temp) {
                System.out.println();
            }else {
                printNumPattern(num1+num2,num2);
            }
            
        }else {
            printNumPattern(num1-num2,num2);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1;
        int num2;

        num1 = scnr.nextInt();
        num2 = scnr.nextInt();
        printNumPattern(num1, num2);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do things after the recursive call, reusing n1 without any calculation:

```
static void p(int n1,int n2){
  System.out.println(n1);
  if(n1<=0)return;
  p(n1-n2,n2);
  System.out.println(n1);
}
```

(I'm typing on phone, that's why I shortened names a little)

Answer (score 1):

For every 'run' of your `printNumPattern`, **all** the variables are unique to just that one run. This goes for `int temp`, and also for `int num1, int num2` (your parameters).

So, in line 2 you say `int temp = num1;`. If `num1` is 0 or below, you then do `if (num1 == temp)`, which will always be true. The `else` (that goes to `printNumPattern(num1+num2,num2);` cannot possibly ever execute.

It sounds like you want `temp` to be the original input. If you want that, keep passing it along in your `printNumPattern` method as third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs may give issues with the code. The author was closest.

```
    int baseVal = num1;
     System.out.print(num1 + " ");
        if(num1 <= 0)
        {
           if (num1 == baseVal)
               return;
         }
           else
         {
           printNumPattern(num1 + num2, num2);
         }
        }
        else
        {
         printNumPattern(num1 - num2, num2);
         System.out.print(num1 + " ");
         }
```

This works on any program I used. zybooks, VS, and notepad++. If its zybooks, the program wants an output without line breaks so thats why there is no ln or f("\n")